# Python Flask server with MQTT subscription

Tags: python, flask, server, ibm-cloud, mqtt

I have a flask server written in Python running on IBM BlueMix. I want this server to listen to a MQTT channel and publish a message when it receives a message. I have the following code but on_connect and on_message are never called.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
def on_connect(client):
    client.publish(topic2, "CONNECTED")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    client.publish(topic2, "MESSAGE")


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World! I am running on port ' + str(port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect('broker.example.com')
    client.subscribe(topic)
    client.publish(topic2, "STARTING SERVER")

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

I've tried client.loop and client.loop_forever but it doesn't work.

EDIT:     client.publish(topic2, "STARTING SERVER") is working, my credentials are removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the details of the broker you want to connect to in the `connect()` function

e.g.

```
...
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect('broker.example.com')
client.subscribe(topic)
...
```

EDIT: you also need to start the network loop. Given this is flask app you will want to start the loop in the background so use the `loop_start` function.

```
...
client.connect('broker.example.com')
client.loop_start()
...
```

You should also move the `subscribe` and `publish` calls to the `on_connect` callback as they need to wait for the connection to have been established before being run.

EDIT2: adding full working code:

```
from flask import Flask
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

app = Flask(__name__)

topic = 'foo'
topic2 = 'bar'
port = 5000

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe(topic)
    client.publish(topic2, "STARTING SERVER")
    client.publish(topic2, "CONNECTED")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    client.publish(topic2, "MESSAGE")


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World! I am running on port ' + str(port)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = mqtt.Client()
    #client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect('localhost')
    client.loop_start()

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: I did this, just hiding my URL.     client.publish(topic2, "STARTING SERVER") is working fine, on_connect and on_message are not called though.

Comment: I tried loop_start() but the method on_message isn't called

Comment: Have you moved the `subscribe` to `on_connect`? Where you have the `subscribe` at the moment it won't actually do anything because the `connect` has not completed

Comment: I did, however I think that on_connect is never called since it also doesn't publish     client.publish(topic2, "CONNECTED")

Comment: Solved! on_connected excepted two more parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use also Flask-MQTT:

https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

There is even functional example how to implement MQTT-SocketIO bridge, which is just what I was looking for. This worked out-of-the-box:

https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#interact-with-socketio